# Symfony FosUserBundle profilePicture

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.1

The problem is that is only uploaded when I change other field. If I just choose to upload file it will not work.

here my class User.php

```
/**
  * @ORM\Entity
  * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
  * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
  */

   class User extends BaseUser
   {
  /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;


 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $nom;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $prenom;




/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $path;

/**
 * @Assert\File(
 *      maxSize = "5M",
 *      mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/tiff"},
 *      maxSizeMessage = "The maximum allowed file size is 5MB.",
 *      mimeTypesMessage = "Only the file types image are allowed.")
 */
public $file;


/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="2048k")
 * @Assert\Image(mimeTypesMessage="Please upload a valid image.")
 */
protected $profilePictureFile;

// for temporary storage
private $tempProfilePicturePath;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $profilePicturePath;



public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // your own logic
}






/**
 * Set nom
 *
 * @param string $nom
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setNom($nom)
{
    $this->nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nom
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNom()
{
    return $this->nom;
}

/**
 * Set prenom
 *
 * @param string $prenom
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setPrenom($prenom)
{
    $this->prenom = $prenom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get prenom
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPrenom()
{
    return $this->prenom;
}



 /**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload() {
    if (null !== $this->file) {
        $this->path = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $this->file->guessExtension();
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload() {
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }
    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);
    unset($this->file);
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeUpload() {
    if ($this->file == $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
        unlink($this->file);
    }
}

public function getAbsolutePath() {
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->path;
}

public function getWebPath(){
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->id . '/' . $this->path;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir() {
    return __DIR__ . '/../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->id;
}

protected function getUploadDir() {
    return 'uploads/users';
}

/**
 * @param string $path
 * @return User
 */
public function setPath($path) {
    $this->path = $path;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getPath() {
    return $this->path;
}

/**
 * Set profilePicturePath
 *
 * @param string $profilePicturePath
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setProfilePicturePath($profilePicturePath)
{
    $this->profilePicturePath = $profilePicturePath;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get profilePicturePath
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getProfilePicturePath()
{
    return $this->profilePicturePath;
}
```

My Overriding FormType ProfileType.php looks something like

```
class ProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('nom')->add('prenom')->add('file');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'fos_user_profile_edit';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }
}
```

Any help

Answer (score 0):

1 - Use VichUploaderBundle that helps you to auplad files.

2 - You have to create a service for your form to override FOS form like this :

```
services:
        class: YouNameSpace\Form\Type\YourFormType
        arguments: ['%fos_user.model.user.class%']
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: user_registration }
```

3- add this to you buildForm method before setting $builder:

```
parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
```